# Python-Storing input variables in a loop with different names per iteration

Tags: python, loops

Here is a simple loop. It is a while loop, but I don't care if it is a for loop or other.

```
answer="y"
counter=1
while answer=="y":
    number=int(input("Enter number: "))
    answer=input("Want to continue? ")
    counter=counter+1
```

I want to store the variables entered in a loop with different variable names (if possible), so that I can do simple comands like:

-print the first number entered

-add 1 to the second number entered

I think it has to do something with the counter, such as

```
    number.counter=number
    print(number.counter)
```

But as you have guessed, it doesn't work;;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not ideal to have variables created `n` number of times to hold values entered in every iteration. There comes the need of something like a list which can hold `n` items:

```
answer = "y"
numbers = []

while answer.lower() == "y":
    numbers.append(int(input("Enter number: ")))
    answer = input("Want to continue? ")
```

<sub>`answer.lower()` is a guaranteed check (assume if user types in Y instead of y)</sub>

Now, this will give first number entered:

```
numbers[0]
```

This adds 1 to second number:

```
numbers[1] + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use defaultdict from collections library to do that task. This will ensure index locations of each input variables.
With the index and variables, you can do the rest.

```
from collections import defaultdict

in_number = defaultdict(list)

loop = True
counter = 1
while loop:

    try:
        number = int(input("Enter number: "))
        in_number[counter] = number
        counter+=1
    # catch errors  
    except Exception as e:
            # find better way to deal with them
        print(e)

    continue_ = input("Want to continue? ")
    if continue_.lower() == 'y':
        loop = True
    else:
        loop = False

print('First number',in_number[1])
if len(in_number)>1:
    print('Second number +1', in_number[2]+1)
```

So, we are using a while loop to populate our users input numbers. Each number is store with its index. We catch error that will be raised if number input is not a float or integer. We ask to continue and modify loop variable. The best thing about that is you can add more continue choices. E.g.

```
continue_.lower() in ['y','yes','ja','continue']
```

Hope this helps give you directions ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use `defaultdict from collections` to store all the numbers and its associated name as a key/value pairs.

```
from collections import defaultdict

answer="y"
dic = defaultdict(list)
counter=1
while answer=="y":
    number = int(input("Enter number: "))
    numberx = 'number'+str(counter)
    dic[numberx] = number
    answer=input("Want to continue? ")
    counter=counter+1
print(dic)
print(dic.items())
print(dic.keys())
print(dic.values())
```

**Output :**

```
(python37) C:\Users\Documents>py test.py
Enter number: 12
Want to continue? y
Enter number: 87
Want to continue? y
Enter number: 90
Want to continue? y
Enter number: 12
Want to continue? n
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'number1': 12, 'number2': 87, 'number3': 90, 'number4': 12})
dict_items([('number1', 12), ('number2', 87), ('number3', 90), ('number4', 12)])
dict_keys(['number1', 'number2', 'number3', 'number4'])
dict_values([12, 87, 90, 12])
```